# How can the arrow stay UP if i hover subnav-content?

Tags: jquery, html, css

i made a jsfiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/g7u0zkyc/1/.

I want the arrow up when i hover the `subnav-content` (see code class).

```
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <div class="navbarSecond">
                    <div class='container'>
                  <div class="subnav">
                    <button class="subnavbtn">NEW RELEASES<i class='subnav-arrow down'></i></button>
                    <div class="subnav-content">
                            <div class='container'>
                                <div class='row'>
                                <div class='col-md-2 margin-right-subnav-links'>
                      <a href="#">test1</a>
                      <a href="#">test2</a>
                    </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>


  .navbarSecond {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: darkgrey;
  }

  .navbarSecond a {
    float: left;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  .subnav {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .subnav .subnavbtn {
    font-size: 14px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 12px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;
  }

  .navbarSecond a:hover, .subnav:hover .subnavbtn {
    background-color: black;
  }

  .subnav-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    background-color: grey;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
  }

  .subnav-content a {
    float: none;
    width:200px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding:5px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .subnav-content a:hover {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: black;
  }

    .subnav-content .normal-subnav-links a {
        text-align: left;
    }

    .subnav-content .normal-subnav-links a:hover {
      background:transparent;
    }

  .subnav:hover .subnav-content {
    display: block;
  }

  .normal-subnav-links a:first-child {
  font-weight: 700;
}


.margin-right-subnav-links {
  margin-right:35px;
}

  .subnav-arrow {
    border: solid white;
    border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-right:0px;
    transition: all 0.10s ease;
  }

  .down {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.up {
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
}

  $('.subnavbtn').hover(function(){
  $(this).children('i').toggleClass('down up');
  });
```

Comment: You mean when you hover on menu items?

Comment: @ElmanHuseynov  Hello thanks for your time and answer. The answer is yes. Do you know how this can work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need JS for it, just remove your JS code, and add this CSS:

```
.subnav:hover i{
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
```

This is a snippet for you as well:

```css
  .navbarSecond {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: darkgrey;
  }

  .navbarSecond a {
    float: left;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  .subnav {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .subnav .subnavbtn {
    font-size: 14px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 12px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;
  }

  .navbarSecond a:hover, .subnav:hover .subnavbtn {
    background-color: black;
  }

  .subnav-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    background-color: grey;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
  }

  .subnav-content a {
    float: none;
    width:200px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding:5px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .subnav-content a:hover {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: black;
  }

    .subnav-content .normal-subnav-links a {
        text-align: left;
    }

    .subnav-content .normal-subnav-links a:hover {
      background:transparent;
    }

  .subnav:hover .subnav-content {
    display: block;
  }

  .normal-subnav-links a:first-child {
  font-weight: 700;
}


.margin-right-subnav-links {
  margin-right:35px;
}

  .subnav-arrow {
    border: solid white;
    border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-right:0px;
    transition: all 0.10s ease;
  }
  
  .down {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.up {
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
}

.subnav:hover i{
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>SlutProjekt </title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata:400,700%7CRaleway:400,700&display=swap"
    rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <!-- JS files: jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
        <!-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
        <div class="navbarSecond">
          <div class='container'>
          <div class="subnav">
            <button class="subnavbtn">NEW RELEASES<i class='subnav-arrow down'></i></button>
            <div class="subnav-content">
              <div class='container'>
                <div class='row'>
                <div class='col-md-2 margin-right-subnav-links'>
              <a href="#">test1</a>
              <a href="#">test2</a>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="subnav">
            <button class="subnavbtn">NEW RELEASES<i class='subnav-arrow down'></i></button>
            <div class="subnav-content">
              <div class='container'>
                <div class='row'>
                <div class='col-md-2 margin-right-subnav-links'>
              <a href="#">test1</a>
              <a href="#">test2</a>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="subnav">
            <button class="subnavbtn">NEW RELEASES<i class='subnav-arrow down'></i></button>
            <div class="subnav-content">
              <div class='container'>
                <div class='row'>
                <div class='col-md-2 margin-right-subnav-links'>
              <a href="#">test1</a>
              <a href="#">test2</a>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add below jquery to your code. Take a look at [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vo69txz5/). Is this expected behaviour?

```
  $('.subnav-content').hover(function(){
    $('.subnavbtn').children('i').toggleClass('down up');
  });
```

EDIT:
I've made some changes to your existing jquery code, so take a look at [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y0p4jLes/) too.

```
$('.subnavbtn, .subnav-content').hover(function(){
  $('.subnavbtn').children('i').toggleClass('down up');
});
```

Comment: Sorry, i FORGOT to say that i have multiple `.subnavbtn` next to eachother and NOW with your code they will go UP all of them if i hover on the first `.subnavbtn` and `.subnav-content` class. That was the hard part for me, i am not great at this.

Comment: Oh, sorry Poemko. I didn't realize that. So take a look at Elman's answer.

Comment: @ElmanHuseynov No sorry if i HOVER over `subnav-content` all the arrows will go up from the `.subnavbtn`

Comment: @Poemko I updated my answer, there are 3 menu items with 3 rows, and only hovered ones icon is turned.